# Excel VBA: Organize selection.address string

Tags: vba, excel

The following sub does exactly what I want it to do but ONLY if the user selects columns from left to right.

Basically, it inserts a column to the left of every column that is selected and applies the formatting specified.

My question is, is there a built in method I can use to organize the address of the selection so that the columns are ordered from left to right?

```
Sub InsertColumns()
Dim Columns() As String
Dim x As Integer

ReDim Columns(UBound(Split(Selection.Address, ",")))

'Organize the string before splitting it into an array?

Columns = Split(Selection.Address, ",")

'Maybe a function to sort the array?

For x = 0 To UBound(Columns)
    Range(Columns(x)).Offset(, x).Select 'Used for debugging
    Range(Columns(x)).Offset(, x).Insert
    With Range(Columns(x)).Offset(, x)
        .ColumnWidth = 1
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

**Notes:**

The selection object only counts as 1 column and I have not figured out a way to loop through every column without using the address. if this is possible another way, I'm open to suggestions.

I take advantage of excels behavior of pushing content right and leaving the selection where it is to apply the formatting to the "new" column. I do not know of a way to get a column that was recently inserted by reference. For instance, would something like the below work?

```
Dim NewCol as Dolumn
Set NewCol = Range(columns(x).Offset(, x).Insert
```

I use the power of math to make sure that the columns are inserted correctly. As we add columns, we need to offset later columns to ensure we are moving over the correct number of columns. This is why x is used to grab a starting column and used to offset the selection by the required amount.

I can totally write code to parse the string or a function to sort the array. I'm looking more for a built in method of doing this.

Again, the sub works exactly as expected. I really just need to find a way to compensate for users who don't follow directions. Any Ideas appreciated!

**EDIT1:** The address string would contain an address such as:

```
$H:$H,$I:$I,$J:$J,$K:$K,$L:$L,$M:$M
```

If you do not select left to right however, the address get's filled in the order the columns are selected. So if I select columns D, F, E in that order, the address is

```
$D:$D,$F:$F,$E:$E
```

As opposed to it's alphabetic order of D, E, F (left to right) which is what I want.

Edit2:

I get that a selection is a range object. What I'm trying to emphasize is as follows:

```
Sub adsfd()
Dim a As Range

Set a = Selection

Debug.Print a.Columns.Count

End Sub
```

Here, the output text is 1 because Cant see the individual columns in the selection.

Areas will work however:

```
Sub adsfd()
Dim a As Range

Set a = Selection

Debug.Print a.areas.count

End Sub
```

This shows the correct number of columns. The problem here, is that they are still out of order

I'd like to emphasize as well - I can make it work. My question is now "How can I do this" It's "Is there a built in way to access the columns in a selection from left to right."

```
dim a as range

for each a in selection
    'This cycles through independent cells. Which is not what I want
next a
```

The best answer thus far still requires going through every cell in the selection. My method does not.

Comment: It would help to provide an example of the Address for the type of selection you want to be able to handle.

Comment: instead of `Address` why don't you just use the `selection` as a `Range` instead?

Comment: I need to access each column individually, Selection.range views all of the columns as 1 column. It cannot differentiate between them.

Comment: no, it does not, you can iterates Selection as as Range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it from right-to-left if that's how the user selected, but it still seems to achieve the stated goal - insert a column to the left of each column selected and format it.

```
Sub inscol()

    Dim rCol As Range
    Dim rNew As Range

    For Each rCol In Selection.Columns
        rCol.Insert
        With rCol.Offset(, -1)
            .ColumnWidth = 1
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
        End With

    Next rCol

End Sub
```

Comment: Can I ask you one more quick question. If Selection.columns stores each column as a separate range, why does selection.columns.count not work accurately? What is the build in way for counting the columns in a selection?

Comment: It has to do with contiguous vs. non-contiguous ranges. If you have a non-contiguous selection then `?Selection.Count` is the same as `?Selection.Areas(1).Count`. The only way to get a true column count for a non-contiguous selection is to loop through the Areas and add up the columns. However, when you iterate through the Columns object, the NewEnum (hidden method that gets the next column) already knows that it may have to deal with multiple Areas and accounts for that. Why `Count` works different than `NewEnum` is beyond me.

Comment: Interesting, Selection.Areas.Count seemed to work fine (with no index). Is there a reason against using this? The only Issue I had was that it was non-contiguous like the selection object. Also, Is there a reason that this loops right to left?

Comment: If each Area is one column, then that will work. But if you select A:B, G:G you would get two Areas and three columns. That may not apply to your particular situation. The code above goes in the same order as the user made the selection. If the user selects the column left-to-right it will go that way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function (e.g below) to find the right-most selected column, then work backwards from that column:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim MaxCol As Long, c As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Selection.EntireColumn
MaxCol = LastCol(rng)
For c = MaxCol To 1 Step -1
    If Not Application.Intersect(Selection.Parent.Columns(c), rng) _
                                                    Is Nothing Then
        'insert your new column
    End If
Next c

End Sub

Function LastCol(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim a As Range, c As Range
    LastCol = 0
    For Each a In rng.Areas
        For Each c In a.Columns
            If c.Column > LastCol Then LastCol = c.Column
        Next c
    Next a
End Function
```